# How to use sqlite database with xampp using php

Tags: php, sqlite

How to install sqlite or sqlite 3 database with xampp server and how to use sqlite or sqlite 3 database using php scripts or programs...

Comment: Have you tried using Google "xampp sqlite3"? [The first result](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=34389) may be what you need. Or do you have a specific question about the installation/usage of the sqlite3-extension?

Comment: @vstm This is actually the first thing that turns up on google.  Yay s.o.  So, we should try to make a solid answer, instead of a 'gtfo' troll comment.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: thank you for the comment. Well there are already two answers to this question which cover checking the driver and actually using the driver (which is from me, so I did not just write the gtfo-comment). I don't know what specific points you (or the OP) are missing to consider the answer "solid".

Comment: @vstm The same thing that is missing in most of the beginner tutorials out there, I imagine: how to configure sqlite to work on one's system (with xampp/lampp/whatever).  What Jorg is saying is that PDO comes with PHP, I think.  I don't know if it's turned on by default or not, personally.  I haven't used it, which is what brought me here.

Comment: I think that PDO is enabled by default in most PHP distros, but since everybody configures PHP when they install it, it would be good to have a configuration guide specific to PDO, somewhere.  It's a good idea to go through all the flags, I think, at least once.

Answer (score 21):

To activate SQLite3 in Xampp (v3.2.2). Open `xampp/php/php.ini`, un-comment the line `;extension=sqlite3` (retrieve the ;), save the `php.ini` and restart your Xampp server.

Answer (score 6):

### Creating the sqlite Database

You have two possibilities to achieve that:

1. Writing your DDL-statements (CREATE TABLE...) in a .sql file and execute it using the sqlite command line (assuming your CREATE TABLE statements are in a file called tabledef.sql):

   ```
   cat tabledef.sql | sqlite3 yourdbname.db
   ```
2. Use PHP to execute the DDL-statements on a connected database (see "Executing statements").

### Connecting to a sqlite Database

You should definitely use PDO to do that:

```php
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:/path/to/your/database.db', '', '', array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
));
```

If the database does not exist, then it is created. But you need write-access to the directory that contains the database. If you permit write-access only to the database file, sqlite fails because it also needs to create a lock file in the same directory.

### Executing statements

Now that you have a connection you can do your stuff with the database, for example execute some DDL-statements:

```php
$dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
    mypk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    myvalue TEXT);");
```

Or if you need to dynamically generate SQL statements, use prepared statements:

```php
$statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (myvalue) VALUES(?)");

$statement->execute(array("hello"));
$statement->execute(array("world"));
```

This is only a small overview, for further information you should check out the [PDO manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) and the [sqlite Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html).

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setup.php - Configuration instructions via the manual.

Answer (score 3):

Well to see if it's installed, check phpinfo() and see if the drivers for sqlite are installed (search the list for "sqlite"), it will mention sqlite and and sqlite 3 seperately. I think they both come preinstalled with XAMPP so it should just work. Then check the PHP manual for [sqlite functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php), or use the PDO wrappers. Google is your friend.

Comment: The php info () shows mysql, odbc, sqlite, sqlite2 are enabled in PDO drivers... I am new to the sqlite database Plz tell how should i create and/or to access a database and table in sqlite using php programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a database wrapper, that can make things much easier.

try this one, i made it :

```
<?php
Class Sqlite3_Wrapper
{

    private $sFileName, $oCon=null, $iDebug, $oResult;
    private $sDefaultFile = 'default.db';

    public function __construct($sFileName, $iDebug=false)
    {
         $this->setFileName($sFileName);
    }

    private function showMessage($sMsg)
    {
         if($this->iDebug != false)
         {
              $sMessage = (php_sapi_name() == 'cli')?$sMsg."\n":$sMsg.'<br />' ;
              echo $sMessage;
         }
    }

    public function setFileName($sFileName)
    {
         if(is_string($sFileName) && strlen($sFileName)>0)
         {
              $this->sFileName = $sFileName;
         }
         else
         {
              $this->sFileName = $this->sDefaultFile;
         }
    }

    public function openDB($sFileName=false)
    {
         if($sFileName!==false)
         {
              $this->setFileName($sFileName);
         }
         try
         {
              $this->oCon = new SQLite3($this->sFileName);
         }catch(Exception $oEx)
         {
              $this->showMessage($ex->getMessage());
         }

    }

    public function closeDB()
    {
         if($this->oCon!=null)
         {
              $this->oCon->close();
              $this->oCon = null;
         }
    }

    public function executeCUDQuery($sQuery)
    {
         if($this->oCon==null)
         {
              $this->showMessage('Not connected to database');
         }
         else
         {
              try
              {
                   $this->oCon->exec($sQuery);
              }catch(Exception $ex)
              {
                   $this->showMessage($ex->getMessage());
              }
         }
    }

    public function executeQuery($sQuery)
    {
         $this->oResult = null;
         if($this->oCon==null)
         {
              $this->showMessage('Not connected to database');
         }
         else{
              try
              {
                   $this->oResult = $this->oCon->query($sQuery);
              }catch(Exception $oEx)
              {
                   $this->showMessage($oEx->getMessage());
              }
         }
         return $this->oResult;
     }

     public function fetch($iMode=SQLITE3_NUM)
     {
     $aData = array();
     try
     {
         $aData = $this->oResult->fetchArray($iMode);
     }
     catch(Exception $oEx)
     {
         $this->showMessage($oEx->getMessage());
     }
     return $aData;
  }
 }
?>
```

or get the files here :

http://vaan3713.github.com/databaseswrappers/

wish it will help.

Comment: Please include all the needed information in you answer. That way you would still have a valid answer when the link goes down. Also please answer the OP while you are at it.